# When plotting, how do I filter out values that have a sum of < 10 in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data list with several columns: `selected`, `total`, `location`. `Location` is plotted on the x-axis and `selected` on the y axis. However, I am looking to filter out the values that have totals of less than 10 for `selected`.

So far, for the plot I have I'm using:

```
ggplot(rawdata) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=location, y=selected)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x=location, y=selected, se=F)) +
  labs(
  title="All bins, selected", 
  x="location", 
  y="selected")
```

Is there a way to do that in `ggplot2`? I'm assuming we'd use an `if` statement to include the third column but I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is possible.

Comment: It's difficult without seeing your data. Either may be done using rawdata[total<10,] or a tidyverse dplyr filter. Post sample data.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including code that generates data in the same form as yours. Often easiest to include the output of `dput(rawdata)` or if that's too long `dput(head(rawdata, XX))` where XX is a number of rows that includes some where `selected` is > 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()` when calling your dataset in the ggplot data argument. In the example below, I've filtered out values of 'cty' that are less than ten.

```
library(tidyverse) 

ggplot(data = filter(mpg, cty >= 10), aes(x = hwy, y = cty)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: I tried using that general syntax and I couldn't get it to work. It says: "Error 'data' must be a data frame or other object coercible by 'fortify()', not an S3 object with class uneval. Did you accidentally pass aes() to the data argument? Backtrace x1." ggplot2 was working just fine when I asked it to plot things earlier with the same data set.